# Docker Volume and C++ std::filesystem::rename

Tags: c++, docker, std-filesystem

I want to serialize game atomically. I use std::filesystem rename for this problem:

```
void SerializeGameAtomic ( const Game & game , fs::path state_file)
{
  std::cout << " Start Atomic Serialization" << std::endl;
  std::string temporary_path = "TemporaryBackup"s;
  std::ofstream output_file;
  output_file.open(temporary_path.data(), std::ios::out);
  if (output_file.is_open()){
    std::cout << "File was created" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "File was not created" << std::endl;
  }
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa{output_file};
  oa << game;
  output_file.close();
  auto state_path = fs::path(state_file);
  fs::create_directories(state_path.parent_path());
  std::cout << "Try Rename" << std::endl;
  fs::rename(fs::path(temporary_path), state_path);
  std::cout << "File was copied" << std::endl;
}
```

It work correctly at local machine and in docker container.
However when i try to use host filesystem in container using volume flag:
`sudo docker run --rm -p 80:8080  -v  /home/work/volume/:tmp/volume:rw   game_server`

I get exception : filesystem error: cannot rename: Invalid cross-device link [TemporaryBackup] [/tmp/volume/state]'

What may cause this exception ?

Comment: Exactly that: Renames are only atomic between files on the same filesystem. Create `output_file` under `state_path.parent_path()` instead of the current working directory.

Comment: I guess the final file may contain corrupt data the way you use it. Regardless, open/close is not the best way to use `fstream`. Just forward parameters to constructor and let destructor close it when scope ends; this gaurantees the archive is closed before file. I'd even put the definition in `if` initialization to limit the lifetime and show intent: `if (std::ofstream ofs{temporary_path, std::ios::out}; ofs.is_open()){/*...*/};` no explicit open/close, less typing while also less error-prone code. Less is more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This comment was very useful and solve my problem:

> Exactly that: Renames are only atomic between files on the same filesystem. Create output_file under state_path.parent_path() instead of the current working directory. –
> Botje

Files exactly should be located at the same filesystem. I use state_path.parent_path() for temporary file.